# How can I make a CSS selector for a button with two classes existing in .less?

Tags: css

I have this CSS:

```
    button {

        background: @button-background;
        color: @text;

        &.focus {
            background-image: linear-gradient(#79d858, #569e3d);
            border-color: #4a993e;
            color: white;
        }
     }
```

How can I make another CSS for when the button has .focus and :hover ? Please note .focus is a class that I add to the button and not anything to do with if a button has focus or not.  Thanks

Comment: You could use `&.focus, &:hover`. Or you may want `&.focus:hover`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
button {

    background: @button-background;
    color: @text;

    .focus {
        background-image: linear-gradient(#79d858, #569e3d);
        border-color: #4a993e;
        color: white;

        &:hover {
            ...
        }
    }
 }
```

NB: ampersand on focus is superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use `&:hover`

```css
button {
  background: @button-background;

color: @text;

&.focus {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#79d858, #569e3d);
    border-color: #4a993e;
    color: white;
    &:hover {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

For further reading, I suggest looking [here](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-nested-rules)